# Floating div's left or right depending on variable WITHOUT columns

Tags: html, css, coldfusion-10, cfml

I'm modifying my current build of one of my pages where there are X amount of boxes with varying content in each box, some float to the left, some float to the right and some fill the whole column space. The way this is currently done is like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="doubleColumn">
    <div class="contentBox"></div>
    <div class="contentBox"></div>

    <div class="singleColumn left">
        <div class="contentBox"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="singleColumn right">
        <div class="contentBox"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.doubleColumn {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.singleColumn {
    width: 49%;
}

.contentBox {
    border: 1px solid RGB(0, 0, 0);
    box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

For the current solution there is no issues as the layout works perfectly and if below the left and right columns i wanted to add another 2 wider content boxes, i simply add those, then perhaps another 2 inside a left column below that. The issue comes when i try to assign variables to determine which box goes where, because i'm trying to make it so we can adjust each box to be either at the top, bottom or middle or wherever else we wish it to be, and also adjust whether it sits on the left, right or fills the whole box. I got a "half-working" solution in which i use the  to run a check that if a boxes position equals one, it fills the space, if it equals 2 it floats left and if it equals 3 it floats right. I'll demonstrate once again below:

**HTML**

```
<cfquery datasource="datasource" name="boxes">
    Select *
    From boxes
    Order by box_order
</cfquery>

<div class="doubleColumn">
    <cfoutput query="boxes">
        <cfif box_position eq 1>
            <div class="contentBox"></div>
        <cfelseif box_position eq 2>
            <div style="clear: left; float: left; width: 49%;">
                <div class="contentBox"></div>
            </div>
        <cfelseif box_position eq 3>
            <div style="clear: right; float: right; width: 49%;">
                <div class="contentBox"></div>
            </div>
        </cfif>
    </cfoutput>
</div>
```

But if I have two in a row that float left, then one that float right it (as it would) floats next to the second one on the left rather than the first one because of using clear, but if i don't use clear then the second left will sit alongside the first left. I'm stuck and don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: This sounds like something that multiple existing UI libraries have already solved. Pick one of those and you'll save yourself a bunch of unnecessary work.

Answer (score 1):

Floating can be very tricky because of the different heights the boxes may have in that case. I used a similar design once for my website and had to come up with a few tricks. Few things that may solve your issue:

1) Whenever you have 2 boxes in a single line (be it both left, both right, or one left and one right) have a div container around it. This way you will isolate them and the third box won't be affected by it. Make sure that box has overflow:hidden. I actually would put overflow:hidden on all of them, this should fix problems you may have with margins.

```
<div class="contentBox"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="singleColumn left"></div>
    <div class="singleColumn left"></div>
</div>
<div class="singleColumn right"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uHVKg/ if you want to play around with it

2) It may be better to have ALL boxes floating left, unless you want the following scenario:
Double column
Single right
Double Column

But then you'll have a hole on the left side.

3) Another solution (that is usually not practical, but can work on few scenarios) is o specify a height for the boxes. But if you have dynamic content, forget about it.